# How do I support self sizing cells on iOS7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, swift, ios8

With the release of iOS8 I have designed my table view with cells taking advantage of self sizing cells. But I need my tables to work in iOS7 as well. How do I do that? Is there a way to check whether self sizing cells is supported or not in runtime, or can I implement some table delegate methods in my controller which will not be called in iOS7?

If I try my table with self sizing cells in iOS7 I get errors on the console like this:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc912d1d5a0 V:|-(>=11)-[UILabel:0x7fc912d13900]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc912d13400 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc912d1d6b0 V:[UILabel:0x7fc912d13900]-(11)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc912d13400 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc912d24d80 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc912d13400(0.5)]>"
)
```

Comment: You can't, iOS 7 does not support the selfsizing cells from iOS 8. You will need to write a `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` dat calculates the correct height for the cell.

Comment: If you need to support iOS7 don't use the self sizing feature.

Comment: I understand self sizing cells are not supported in iOS7. My issue is what to do with tables designed for iOS8 using self sizing cells. E.g. will tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: only get called on iOS7 but not on iOS8? In short, how do I write code that works for both iOS7 and iOS8?

Comment: You can have a look at my weekend project: https://github.com/ruuki/MBCollectionView it is not ready for even beta, it can be only alpha in the best case but it is an attempt to implement an Android-like-UITableView

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the solution I have found thus far, but it requires checking for specific version number rather than capability. You only set `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` if you have iOS 8 or higher as version:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    if NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 {
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

For iOS 7 you need to calculate a height for each cell. But if you are on iOS 8 you can return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` as the height:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
    return 50 // Or whatever calculated value you need for cell height
}
```

Comment: Worked for me as well but I needed to add ()'s around the if statement. Also you don't need else if you return in the if.

Comment: This will break for iOS versions more recent than 7.1. I'd rather check for features (i.e. using `respondsToSelector`) or with < 8.0.

Comment: How can i do that for objective c can you post for that too

Answer (score 1):

For iOS versions older than 8.0, you can always write the usual `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method where you create a cell, run an auto layout pass on it and then return the actual height.