# Removing heightForRowAtIndexPath: compatibility with iOs7

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios8, heightforrowatindexpath

In the new iOs8, if I don't implement the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, a row with multiple lines will be displayed with the right height.
But, if I want to preserve the back compatibility to iOs7, I need the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method to be implemented...
How can I implement this only in iOs8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use define rule:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Here how you should use it:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (!SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"))
        return 100.0;//your custom height here
    else
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: A similar solution without defining macro: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26283017/936957